# Mix between Pivot and Panorama for Windows Phone App

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, panorama-control

Just a quick reminder. That's what a Panorama look like. All the pages except the last one display a part of the next page.
[image]

This is what a Pivot look like. All the pages are "fullscreen"
[image]

I would like to create a control that would be a mix between the Pivot and the Panorama control. Here is what I would like to have:

[image]

The middle page would be fullscreen, the left and the right page would contain a part of the middle page. But I don't know how to do it. I tried both Panorama and Pivot with some fiddling of the pages margins but without success. Do you know how to do it?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found an answer by digging a lot on the web: http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.fr/2013/08/add-lateral-menus-to-windows-phone.html

This answer suggests to make your own Panorama / Pivot with a canvas and to move left/right the pages with a storyboard.

Hope it can help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a blog posts that details a behavior based solution:
http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.nl/2013/09/a-behavior-to-implement-scroll-into.html

And a second that directly references the Facebook UI, and shows how to implement the proper gestures for the dragging and snapping:
http://depblog.weblogs.us/2013/07/30/facebook-like-settings-pane-with-gestures-windows-phone/

Comment: Link only answers are not welcome in StackOverflow. You should post essential part from links as answer.

Comment: Added some additional context to the links